# numpy arrays: building a 3d array by adding 2d slices one at a time

Tags: arrays, numpy, reshape

Looking for some help with numpy and building a 3d array from multiply 2d arrays. I want to make a loop, such that on every iteration I make a new 2d array and make it a new slice in an existing 3d array. Here's my code sample.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import array
a = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(10, 10))    <-- make random 10x10 matrix
b = a                                         <-- save copy
a = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(10, 10))    <-- make random 10x10 matrix
a.shape
(10, 10)                                      <-- verify it's 10x10
b.shape
(10, 10)                                      <-- verify it's 10x10
b = np.array([b, a])                          <-- convert two 2d matrix into one 3d matrix
b.shape
(2, 10, 10)                                   <-- verify it's a 3d matrix with two planes
a = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(10, 10))    <-- make new random 10x10 matrix
b = np.array([b, a])                          <-- add new 2d plane to the 3d matrix
b.shape
(2,)                                          <-- should be (3, 10, 10)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first `np.array([b,a])` combines two (10,10) arrays to make a (2,10,10).  Notice that it added a dimension, joining 2 identical shaped array.  Why should the second with a (2,10,10) and a (10,10) to do the same?  Just because you want to?  What you should be doing is `np.array([a,b,a1,a2,..])` - joining a list of `n` identically shaped arrays to make a (n,10,10).

Answer (score 0):

When you combine two arrays by using `np.array([...])`, they have to be the same shape. If they aren't numpy treats them not as numpy arrays, but as dumb/blind objects. There should have been a warning when you ran the last `b = np.array([b, a])`:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
```

Instead, use `np.stack`

```
b = np.stack([*b, a])
```

`*b` basically expands the children of `b`, so the above is equivalent to `b = np.stack([b[0], b[1], a])`

Or you can use `np.vstack` (vertical stack):

```
b = np.vstack([b, a[None]])
```

`a[None]` basically wraps `a` in another array. `a.shape == (10, 10)`, `a[None].shape == (1, 10, 10)`

Both of the above produce the following:

```
>>> b.shape
(3, 10, 10)

>>> b
array([[[3, 8, 0, 2, 8, 0, 0, 5, 7, 7],
        [0, 5, 2, 8, 8, 2, 1, 4, 5, 8],
        [3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 8, 2, 0, 7, 5],
        [5, 6, 5, 0, 8, 7, 4, 0, 4, 6],
        [6, 2, 3, 7, 4, 3, 6, 6, 4, 8],
        [2, 5, 1, 7, 1, 3, 0, 6, 0, 5],
        [3, 4, 0, 7, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 4],
        [0, 7, 2, 8, 7, 7, 4, 3, 2, 6],
        [4, 6, 2, 5, 5, 8, 5, 8, 0, 8],
        [3, 4, 1, 0, 3, 7, 0, 6, 7, 3]],

       [[4, 0, 6, 2, 4, 4, 7, 0, 7, 2],
        [5, 8, 5, 8, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6],
        [2, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 3, 0, 0],
        [8, 7, 3, 0, 8, 8, 0, 4, 1, 4],
        [0, 2, 5, 7, 5, 3, 0, 5, 1, 7],
        [1, 5, 8, 0, 2, 6, 5, 0, 3, 2],
        [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 8, 6, 6, 5, 5],
        [5, 3, 6, 8, 0, 3, 0, 8, 8, 3],
        [4, 2, 6, 6, 6, 2, 0, 0, 6, 2],
        [7, 3, 8, 0, 7, 1, 1, 8, 6, 2]],

       [[6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 4, 6, 2, 6, 7],
        [0, 5, 6, 7, 5, 0, 0, 5, 8, 2],
        [6, 6, 1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2],
        [0, 3, 7, 6, 4, 5, 3, 1, 7, 2],
        [7, 6, 3, 0, 1, 7, 8, 3, 8, 5],
        [3, 1, 8, 6, 1, 5, 0, 8, 6, 1],
        [1, 4, 8, 1, 7, 0, 1, 1, 5, 3],
        [2, 1, 4, 8, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7],
        [8, 1, 1, 0, 6, 1, 0, 6, 1, 6],
        [1, 8, 4, 7, 7, 5, 0, 3, 8, 6]]])
```

Comment: Repeated `stack` or `vstack`, even when it works, does a lot more copying  than list appends.

Comment: Thank you. Wrapped in a loop for a 3d matrix.
"
    >>> a = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(10, 10))
    >>> a.shape
    (10, 10)
    >>> b = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(10, 10))
    >>> b.shape
    (10, 10)
    >>> b=np.array([b, a])
    >>> b.shape
    (2, 10, 10)
    >>> for i in range(10):
            a = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(10, 10))
            b = np.stack([*b, a])
            b.shape

    (3, 10, 10)
    (4, 10, 10)
    (5, 10, 10)
    (6, 10, 10)
    (7, 10, 10)
    (8, 10, 10)
    (9, 10, 10)
    (10, 10, 10)
    (11, 10, 10)
    (12, 10, 10)
"